# whats wrong with my script (key press, python)

Tags: python, pyautogui, msvcrt

I just wanted to make a simple script that key presses "4" seven times, if I press "4" once.

I want it to work in the background while, and work any time I key press "4"

here is what I tried

```
import pyautogui
import time
import msvcrt

while True:
    key = msvcrt.getch().lower()

    if key == b'4':
        for x in range(1,7):
            pyautogui.press(4)
            time.sleep(0.3)
        break
```

I tried to execute this on console and it didn't work. No errors pop up, but no matter how many times I press 4, it doesn't make me press 4 7 more times.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `pyautogui.press` takes a string (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)

Comment: ...and pyautogui.press writes in another window's context, not the one where your program runs...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pyautogui.press('4')
```

From the documentation press takes strings, if it doesn't work you can also try:

```
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        if str(msvcrt.getch()) == b'4':
            for _ in range(7):
                pyautogui.press('4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "4":
        for x in range(0,5):
            pyautogui.press('4')
            time.sleep(0.3)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) could be a solution but we always try to be as universal as possible so I recommend to use a more apropriate library or module like [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) to get pressed keys.

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('4'):
    # do anything
```